# Need an example for Tensor-board implementation in Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, real-time, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to monitor scalars in tensor-board, to set a good configuration for a neural network.

I'm not able to implement tensorboard properly. I've tried **ngrok** method (explained in [this blog post](https://www.dlology.com/blog/quick-guide-to-run-tensorboard-in-google-colab/)), and **google's tensorboard in notebook** method (explained in [tensorflow.org tensorboard in notebooks](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/docs/tensorboard_in_notebooks.ipynb)).

But google's method is not suitable for real time monitoring (after every epoch).
Ngrok seems promising to me but it's not adding scalars to tensorboard to monitor.

So I request you all to please provide me a working python example implementation of Ngrok method in Colab, in which I can monitor the training progress in realtime.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is a 3rd method using Tensorboard.dev

https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/docs/tbdev_getting_started.ipynb

Sometimes, the 2nd method won't work, so try this one too.

Comment: Thank you for replying. It works, but not in real-time. Can you suggest me a way to check the scalars epoch by epoch in real-time. Like after every epoch, I should be able to check. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how. I guess you can try to fix the 2nd method somehow.